# Emscripten fundamentally incompatable with clang on linux

Tags: javascript, c, linux, clang

A long time ago I wrote a really crude and primitive shell in C++, and I only
just recently discovered asm.js, so I thought it'd be neat to try to compile and run it in a browser, but I can't because the apt-packages are incompatible. I installed the llvm, clang, and emscripten packages and they're all up-to-date with what's in the repos. Here's my test file, `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine with `clang hello.c && ./a.out`, but when I run `emcc hello.c` I get the error

`/usr/bin/lli: error creating EE: No available targets are compatible with this triple, see -version for the available targets.
FAIL: Running the generated program failed!`

which *does* generate `a.out.js`, but it only contains the first line reference to `a.out.js.map` as it's SourceMap (the map itself only contains the line: `{"version":3,"file":"a.out.js","sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":""}`. Now I THINK this means that the llvm wasn't compiled with `-targets=all`, or at least without the `js` target, so I tried building it from source. I fetched the latest packages, meticulously following the steps outlined [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_emscripten_from_source_on_linux.html) and [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_fastcomp_manually_from_source.html#building-fastcomp-from-source), and both packages built successfully. However, when run like this, emiscript complained that it 'expected 3.4' but got '(tags/RELEASE_380/final)' for the version information, and subsequently fails. Just to be safe, I had apt-purged emscripten, llvm and clang before starting the source build, and I would hope that 3.4 is the *minimum* version, not the *only supported* version, because the latest build is 3.9 I believe, and the docs didn't say to take any special consideration. Anyway, I tried building the 3.4 from source, but apparently it doesn't recognize 'js' as a valid target (I tried building without that and running it anyway: no dice). It's bizarre to me that the `emscripten` apt-package doesn't pull in the properly-compiled clang/llvm as a dependency, so am I maybe doing the invocation wrong? The docs say I should just be able to do what I'm doing, but I'm new to clang/emscripten, so maybe I have to set up the clang environment first, or alternatively explicitly link something?

## SYSINFO

clang/clang++ version and info (from `clang --version`):

```
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

llvm version and info (from `lli --version`):

```
LLVM version 3.8.0

Optimized build.
Built Jul  9 2016 (11:22:59).
Default target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Host CPU: broadwell
```

emscripten version (from `emcc --version`): 1.22.1

contents of most recently-generated `~/.emscripten_sanity`: `1.22.1|le32-unknown-nacl|/usr/bin|(tags/RELEASE_380/final)`

[paste of most recently-generated `~/.emscsripten`](http://pastebin.com/2xvp8AxL)

kernel info (from `uname -srpmio`): `Linux 4.4.0-21-generic i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

System is a VirtualBox VM with extensions installed, running Linux Mint 18 "Sarah" Cinnamon as a 32-bit machine with 2 CPU cores, 4GB RAM, 512mb Video Memory, and ~50GB virtual disk image. No other OS's are present, basically a vanilla install. Currently has the default versions of clang, llvm and emscripten made available by the apt repositories.

Comment: In case anybody stumbles on this, I was able to circumvent everything by using emsdk. Originally, I couldn't because the C compiler ran out of memory on my 32-bit machine when trying to compile clang, but I added `--build-Release -j1` and was able to cut memory usage by 75% and successfully compile (because it generated literal gigabytes of debug data otherwise).